# Why does the constant of integration move?

Tags: integration, constants, euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm trying to make sense of a solution to a *separation of variables* question. Namely where it goes from:

$$y = \exp(-\cos x + C)$$

To:

$$y = A\cdot \exp(-\cos x)$$

I understand the constant of integration can be quite flexible (oxymoron) in its undefined state but I'm trying to track down an explanation for this particular "identity". This isn't one of the standard exponential identities.

Comment: $e^{a+b} = e^a\cdot e^b$  in your case since $C$ is a constant , $e^C$ is also a constant. Hence it is written as $A$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the addition exponent rule in disguise, with base $b$ and exponents $d$ and $c$:

$$b^{d+c} = b^d \cdot b^c$$

In this case:

$$\exp(-\cos x + C) = e^{-\cos x + C} = e^{-\cos x}\cdot e^C$$

And by renaming $e^C$ to $A$, since both are just constants, we get:

$$A \cdot e^{-\cos x} = A\cdot\exp(-\cos x)$$

Comment: Thank you for filling in the blanks. These kind of "disguised" steps are always a stumbling block of mine.

Comment: @MarkA.Ropper No problem, and I agree. I remember the first time I saw the derivation of the exponential growth function through the differential equation $y' = ky$ and it made a lot more sense where the $A$ came from.

Answer (score 2):

One has
$$
e^{-\cos x+C}=e^{C}\cdot e^{-\cos x}=A\cdot e^{-\cos x}
$$ with
$$
A=e^{C}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We get $$e^{C-\cos(x)}=e^C\cdot e^{-\cos(x)}$$